# What is the name of the hardware used to build this dinner console table?

Tags: table

What is the name of the hardware used to build this dinner console table?
If you are aware of a similar design I would really appreciate some links. I am looking for a dinner table that has to be "almost invisible" when not in use.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

They're called [table slides](https://www.google.com/search?q=table+slides) or extension slides.  They generally come in 2 versions - one for pedestal type tables (sometimes called equalizer slides) and one for traditionally legged tables.

As far as the design goes, you're pretty much limited to your imagination and woodworking ability. Just build it like you would any other extending table, but with the fixed table top only long enough to accommodate the hardware.

Comment: that is specialized hardware they are not regular table slides...

Comment: @user2059078 - I'm not sure what you mean by "regular" table slides. They look like heavy duty steel slides designed for a roughly 6' opening.  How the slide itself is designed really doesn't matter as long as it opens as far as you want it to and is rated for the weight you intend to put on it.

Comment: With a bit of work, you could probably adapt regular drawer slides to perform the same function. Just put sets of them back to back for as much length as you need. They wouldn't be structural, so you'd need intermediate support, or a really stiff tabletop. (Which brings up the problem of where you store a really big and heavy tabletop, but maybe that's another question...)

Comment: @Comintern: they don't. The actual opening goes as far as 115"

Comment: @Aloysius Defenestrate: that is the point, not to have to store a table top or the table itself. The table top must be modular, it expands with the rails (you add more planks) http://www.godownsize.com/goliath-table-extreme-folding-table/  So again: are these specialized rails available off the shelf or they are custom made by the manufacturer?

Comment: It looks like the manufacturer has stacked/crossboltted multiple off the shelf slides, plus affixing the additional support legs... but I can't be at all sure from the photo.

Comment: @user2059078 - So they're table slides that open up to 115" - they're still table slides.  If you can't find slides that long, one option would be to use 4 equalizer slides to bridge 2 pedestals.  The pedestals would then move apart as the 2 sets of slides opened.

Comment: Probably you need 4 of these http://www.hardwaretree.com/proddetail.php?prod=DTL-3506U  There must be longer ones ...this model extends to 68" "only"

Comment: Here is the original manufacturer for this. It is in China and I need to order 100 pairs. http://fsweihua.en.alibaba.com/product/513433831-213090363/48mm_width_adjustable_extension_folding_table_slide.html

Comment: Hypothetically, you could be a manufacturer, seeking a couple of samples to consider production...

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.hardwaretree.com/proddetail.php?prod=DTL-3506U)
is the only one I've found, after being inspired by the same table.
But I did buy them, and I can stretch a small table for 2 to a table for 8-10.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. We discourage answers where the bulk of the information is on the end of a link, because it isn't durable over time (links decay). If you could edit at least some of the information from the link into your answer (e.g. a picture, or a description of the hardware) it would help.